# Query runtime regressed from 80 seconds to >1900 seconds despite Same Plan and Logical Reads

Tags: query-performance, sql-server-2016, query-store

I have enabled Query Store on a development Data Warehouse SQL Server to try and work out which queries that are part of the overnight Data Warehouse build have inconsistent run times. The server runs the same queries every night against the same data so for each query the number of rows affected are the same

My methodology to find the queries with the highest variance is - "all the queries where the difference between the longest Average duration and shortest average duration is over 600 seconds"

the query to do this is as follows:

```
USE MyDB

SELECT  p.plan_id,
        qt.query_sql_text,
        q.query_id,
        count_executions,
        [max_duration],
        min_duration,
        avg_rowcount,
        avg_cpu_time,
        avg_dop,
        avg_query_max_used_memory,
        p.count_compiles
INTO    #queries
FROM    sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
        JOIN sys.query_store_plan p
            ON rs.plan_id = p.plan_id
        JOIN sys.query_store_query q
            ON p.query_id = q.query_id
        JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qt
            ON q.query_text_id = qt.query_text_id
WHERE   qt.query_sql_text NOT LIKE '(%' AND
        q.is_internal_query = 0 

/* queries by largest variance */
SELECT  query_sql_text,
        query_id,
        plan_id,
        count_compiles,
        MaxDegParalellism,
        AllExecutions,
        MaxAvgCPUTime / 1000000 AS MaxAvgCPUTimeSecs,
        QueryMaxUsedMemory,
        MaxAcrossAll / 1000000 AS LongestExecutionSecs,
        MinAcrossAll / 1000000 AS ShortestExecutionSecs,
        (MaxAcrossAll - MinAcrossAll) / 1000000 AS VarianceInSeconds,
        MinAvgRowCount,
        MaxAvgRowCount
FROM    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY query_id ORDER BY query_id) AS RowN,
                    query_sql_text,
                    query_id,
                    plan_id,
                    SUM(count_executions) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS AllExecutions,
                    MAX([max_duration]) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MaxAcrossAll,
                    MIN(min_duration) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MinAcrossAll,
                    MIN(avg_rowcount) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MinAvgRowCount,
                    MAX(avg_rowcount) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MaxAvgRowCount,
                    MAX(avg_cpu_time) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MaxAvgCPUTime,
                    MAX(avg_dop) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS MaxDegParalellism,
                    MAX(avg_query_max_used_memory) OVER (PARTITION BY query_id) AS QueryMaxUsedMemory,
                    count_compiles
            FROM    #queries
        ) a
WHERE   RowN = 1 AND
        (MaxAcrossAll - MinAcrossAll) / 1000000 > 600
ORDER BY VarianceInSeconds DESC
```

from here, I then run a separate query below to drill into the particular `query_id`s of interest:

```
SELECT  qt.query_sql_text,
        p.plan_id,
        TRY_CONVERT(XML,p.query_plan),
        p.[compatibility_level],
        p.is_parallel_plan,
        p.last_compile_duration / 1000000 last_compile_durationSecs,
        q.query_parameterization_type_desc,
        s.first_execution_time AS FirstExecutionEndTime,
        s.last_execution_time AS LastExecutionEndTime,
        s.count_executions,
        s.avg_duration / 1000000 AS AvgDurationSeconds ,
        s.avg_rowcount,
        s.avg_logical_io_reads,
        s.avg_physical_io_reads,
        s.avg_logical_io_writes,
        s.avg_cpu_time / 1000000 AS AvgCPUTimeSeconds, 
        s.avg_dop,
        s.execution_type_desc
FROM    sys.query_store_query q
        LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_plan p
            ON q.query_id = p.query_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats s
            ON s.plan_id = p.plan_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qt
            ON q.query_text_id = qt.query_text_id
WHERE   q.query_id IN (96871)
ORDER BY FirstExecutionEndTime
```

One query in particular has caught my eye and the runtime info is as follows:

[image]

As can be seen from the `AvgDurationSeconds` column, the query is pretty stable, running in around 80 seconds almost every night.

There is one exception that is a massive outlier (highlighted) - the execution on `2021-11-24 00:11:12.4900000 +00:00` which took 1986 seconds despite the logical reads being comparable and the row count and execution plan being the same

Although cropped from the screenshot, the `AvgCPUTimeSeconds` is consistently between 150 and 159, with it being 179 on the long run

The only difference that stands out to me is the time of day the query ran - usually it runs around 9:30 - 10PM but on this occasion it ran just before midnight. The other slight outlier with execution time `2021-12-10 00:48:13.5270000 +00:00` also ran at a later time

The (Anonymized) query is as follows:

```
UPDATE  Table1
SET     Column1 = CASE
                        WHEN Table1.Column2 IS NULL
                        THEN '9'
                        WHEN Table1.Column2 IN(SELECT [Data] FROM MyTVF(Table2.Column1, ','))
                        THEN 'Y'
                        ELSE 'N'
                END
FROM    Table1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 
            ON 'MyValue' = Table2.Column2
```

Some investigation so far:

- I checked our Blocked Process Report for blocking but there was nothing around that time
- I looked at Perfmon traces that we collect nightly to see if the CPU cores (16 of them) were maxed out around that time and whilst there are spikes, it doesn't appear to have been saturated
- There are no backups or index rebuilds run on this server due to it being a development server
- CheckDB is performed once a week on a Sunday (the day in question is a Wednesday)
- The server is a VM and I believe the storage is a SAN

How would I go about understanding what caused the query to run slow over given the investigation already done above? We are on SQL Server 2016 so unfortunately can't get query store wait stats which may have helped.

What might have caused such a vast regression of this query? I would usually put such large swing down to being a different plan but we can see that the plan is consistent throughout.

Comment: Is this a repeatable issue or that was a one-off occurrence? If it's repeatable, you might find logging Adam Machanic's [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to a table, frequently, to see if it exposes what else is running at the same time your above query runs slow.

Comment: I know you said that you checked the blocked process report, but your screenshot cuts off the CPU column. How does CPU time compare to duration? If it’s much lower, it’s likely not then query you’re looking at that’s the problem.

Comment: Hi @ErikDarling good shout. I've updated the question with the information. Its 170 seconds which is mostly in line with all the other runs. This is therefore a "long running low CPU query" as per: https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/long-running-low-cpu/ there are many reasons, two being blocking and linked server queries (both ruled out in this case) The other reasons are "poor client code" (it has a TVF so maybe that is an issue) and waiting on other resources / CPU (not sure how I would find this without the wait stats)

Comment: It was encountering some type of wait. Blocked process report only contains waits that are (a) individually of long duration rather than many smaller waits (b) Of a type that the deadlock monitor looks for,